# Omniture capture previous value

Tags: javascript, selenium, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

So I am new to Java, Omniture analytic and Javascript.

I am working on a task to automate the webpage (using Selenium) which includes click on all the links and capture the **Omniture** value.

Here is the line which is giving me the variable value of Omniture:

```
System.out.println((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return s.<variable name>;").toString();
```

My problem is:
We have **conversion variable eVar30** associated with one link (which I need to capture), now when I click this link it takes me to next page and eVar30 is lost. Means I am not getting that variable at all on next page.

When I googled about how to capture value from previous page, I found below line which will execute Javascript and return the value from previous page:

```
s.getPreviousValue(v,c,e);
```

**[Here](http://webanalyticsland.com/sitecatalyst-plugins/getpreviousvalue)** is more information on that.

Now my Question is, **how can I get this eVar30 value from previous page**.

Answer (score 0):

In order to persist a value from one page to the next you have 2 options:

1. Use server side code to store the appropriate value and then output on the subsequent page(s) (in s.eVar30="my value" for example).  This is great if you want to permanently store a vlaue against a user and they are authenticated.
2. Use client side code (including s.getPreviousValue plugin) to persist the value by dropping it into a cookie.  This is better if the user does not authenticate and you want to persist the values across sessions.

In your case, you may feel that using option 2 is best, and you want to use the s.getPreviousValue plugin.  What you need to know about this plugin is all it does is drops the value you want to persist into a cookie for retrieval later.

To implement this you need to follow these steps:

1. Insert the s.getPreviousValue plugin code into the plugins section of you s_code or app code (depending which version you are using).
2. inside your s_doPlugins() function in the s_code/app code, insert the line:
   `s.eVar30 = s.getPreviousValue(s.eVar30, 'gpv_v30', '[event]')`

This line of code will fire on every page and insert the value that is currently in the cookie called 'gpv_v30' into s.eVar30.  In order to initially store the data into the cookie, you need to specify an event in the 3rd argument.  when this event is set in s.events, the current value of s.eVar30 is stored into the cookie.

If you have no event that triggers this then you can omit the 3rd argument but that will cause the value of the cookie to be updated with the current s.eVar30 value on each tracking call.

If you need any in depth help with Adobe Analytics and you are unable to share your code here we provide a [Adobe Analytics Workshop](http://dmpg.co.uk/adobe-analytics-workshop/) service which is a community service at no cost whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion but let's say I don't have control over the code (server/client) and I still want to get the value, is it still possible? I have checked the cookies as well and I don't think they are storing `eVar30` value in it. And I've multiple links which I need to click one-by-one and all of them have their own `eVar30` value which I need to capture. Any thoughts?

Comment: so let me just get this straight, you don't have any control over server or client side code?

Comment: I can view, but can't edit. The reason I ask is if I can get the value without any changes to code, would be great. If not I might have to ask the developers to make the changes in code.

Comment: sorry, this is quite a strange request.  If you want to send tracking that persists the s.eVar30 value for all of your user you're going to have to make code changes.  If you just want to get what the evar30 value was on the previous page for your own personal session (just so you can see it) just use developer console and type in `s.eVar30` and press enter - do this on every page and you'll know what it was on the page before. To be honest it sounds like you need some greater level of support - why not get in touch and we can discuss whether we can make your life easier!